# I have a basic database up for my app. Im trying to sum the iScore and store it but am not sure how

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to sum the iScore and display and maybe store it but am not sure how.

```
public String getData() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_SCORE, KEY_PUTTS };

    Cursor c = csDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iScore = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE);
    int iPutts = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PUTTS);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iScore) + " " +
                c.getString(iPutts) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please accept my edits, your current question has low quality and make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do, but:
if you want to sum the numbers in KEY_SCORE, then

```
result = result + c.getString(iScore);
```

or

```
  result = result + c.getString(1);
```

OR:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_SCORE = "pscore";
    public static final String KEY_PUTTS = "pputts";
```

then in the getData method:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { "_id","sum(pscore)","pputts" },
                    null,null,null , null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to 'sum' strings. `+` is the concatenate operator. Convert them to numbers and then add them together.